# Installing rootless docker with uidmap installed in .local

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

I am trying to install docker rootlessly. We don't have package `uidmap` installed to the system, so I installed it in `$HOME/.local` by compiling it by myself.

I am on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

The compile process was executed like this

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.local/src
cd $HOME/.local/src
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/shadow/shadow_4.8.1.orig.tar.xz
tar xf shadow_4.8.1.orig.tar.xz
cd shadow_4.8.1
./configure --prefix=$HOME/.local
make -j
make install
```

After installing the shadow (uidmap), I logged out and logged back in to get the `$PATH` set right. (You can source the `$HOME/.profile` too). `newuidmap` was installed correctly.

The rootlesskit failes with this error

```
Sep 27 14:44:14 ubuntu-server dockerd-rootless.sh[3117122]: + exec rootlesskit --net=slirp4netns --mtu=65520 --slirp4netns-sandbox=auto --slirp4netns-seccomp=auto --disable-host-loopback --port-driver=builtin --copy-up=/etc --copy-up=/run --propagation=rslave /home/rldocker/bin/dockerd-rootless.sh
Sep 27 14:44:14 ubuntu-server dockerd-rootless.sh[3117122]: [rootlesskit:parent] error: failed to setup UID/GID map: newuidmap 3117138 [0 1002 1 1 231072 65536] failed: newuidmap: write to uid_map failed: Operation not permitted
Sep 27 14:44:14 ubuntu-server dockerd-rootless.sh[3117122]: : exit status 1
```

If I install `uidmap` by the package (where I have root access), it works as a charm.

Is it a limitation or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Output stat /var/run/docker.sock?

Comment: @RichardRublev It's not a normal docker installation so it does not have a `/var/run/docker.sock`

Answer (score 0):

When installing the package, or as `root`, the `newuidmap` and `nwegidmap` are changed via `setcap cap_setuid+ep`: did you try doing that in your manually built binaries?
See also [here](https://github.com/shadow-maint/shadow/blob/master/src/Makefile.am#L163C2-L163C22)